# How to interpret poission regression coefficients?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I am given the following problem: Suppose that we observe $n$ independent count outcomes, where $n/2$ are from class 0, coded as $0$, and $n/2$ are from class 1, coded with $1$. The sample mean of counts from class 0 is $\bar y_0$, and from class 1, $\bar y_1$. Question: Write down the appropriate type of regression for measuring the effoct of class on the avarage counts, including the equation for the mean, and the interpretion of the intercept $a$ and slope $b$ parameters. The following solution is provided:

\begin{align}log(\mu)=&\;a+bX \implies \mu=exp(a+bX)\\\\
exp(a)=&\;\text{mean of counts from class 0}\\
\implies a =&\;log(\text{mean of class 0})\\\\
exp(a+b) =&\; \text{mean of counts from class 1}\\
\implies a+b =&\;log(\text{mean of class 1})\\
\implies b =&\; log(\text{mean of class 1}) - log(\text{mean of class 0})
\end{align}
This is just the analysis for a general model. Now, plugging in the given values for the means yields
\begin{align}
a=&\;log(\bar y_0)\\
b=&\;log(\bar y_1) - log(\bar y_0).\\
\end{align}

The first line is just the model definition. But I don't understand the interpretation of $a$ and $b$. Maybe a geometric/visual example would make it easier too. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to ask what logarithms mean?

Comment: No, I don't understand how I come to the interpretretation of $exp(a)$ being the mean of counts from class 0, same thing for $exp(a+b)$.

Comment: What happens when you plug in $X=0$?  What happens when you plug in $X=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understand it. $a=log(\bar y_0)$ is the intercept of the fitted line and corresponds to the mean of the class coded as 0 (or whichever class happens to be assigned to the intercept). $b=log(\bar y_1) - log(\bar y_0)$ is the change of class 1 relative to the intercept.

See if this example helps. It's R but hopefully you can follow even if you don;t use R. This dataset has 3 classes, 0, 1, 2:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 15
y <- rpois(n= n, lambda= rep(c(5, 15, 10), each= n/3))
class_type <- rep(c(0, 1, 2), each= n/3)
counts <- data.frame(
    y= y,
    class_type
)

counts
#   y class_type
#   2          0
#   6          0
#   5          0
#   6          0
#   7          0
#  16          1
#  12          1
#  16          1
#  12          1
#  18          1
#   8          2
#   7          2
#   6          2
#  12          2
#  14          2
```

This is a plot of the dataset with red crosses for the group means:

[image]

When entered in R using `glm(y ~ x)` the right hand side is internally transformed into this design matrix:

```
design <- cbind(intx= 1, 
    class_1= rep(c(0,1,0), each= n/3), 
    class_2= rep(c(0,0,1), each= n/3))

design
#  intx class_1 class_2
#     1       0       0
#     1       0       0
#     1       0       0
#     1       0       0
#     1       0       0
#     1       1       0
#     1       1       0
#     1       1       0
#     1       1       0
#     1       1       0
#     1       0       1
#     1       0       1
#     1       0       1
#     1       0       1
#     1       0       1
```

Because the first column is 1, this corresponds to the intercept and in this case is the mean of class 0 (the first class found).

When fitted, the model gives these coefficients:

```
fit <- glm(y ~ 0 + design, family= poisson)
summary(fit)

# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# designintx       1.649      0.196    8.41  < 2e-16 ***
# designclass_1    1.046      0.228    4.59  4.5e-06 ***
# designclass_2    0.592      0.244    2.42    0.015 *
```

So $a$ in your case is 1.649 or on the linear scale $e^{1.649} = 5.2$. Mean of class 1 is $e^{1.649 + 1.046} = 14.8$. Mean of class 2: $e^{1.649 + 0.592} = 9.4$.

In your case $b = \log(14.8) - \log(5.2) = 1.046$ (same as the coefficient reported by R for class 1). In R:

```
intercept <- exp(fit$coefficient[2]) # Or mean of class 0
mean_class_1 <-  exp(fit$coefficient[2] + fit$coefficient[2])
mean_class_2 <-  exp(fit$coefficient[2] + fit$coefficient[3])
```

Code for plot:

```
gg <- ggplot(data= counts, aes(x= jitter(class_type, factor= 0.25), y= y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data= data.frame(class_type= unique(class_type), y= c(intercept, mean_class_1, mean_class_2)), pch= 4, colour= 'red', size= 5) +
    xlab('Class type')
```